# Adding interactions of xreg with lags

Tags: r, arima

My R code now looks like this:

```
model <- arima(data[data$Date<as.Date("2018-01-01"),]$Revenue, 
               order=c(6,0,0), xreg=xreg, method="CSS-ML")
```

which gives me coefficients of AR1 to AR7 and all variables in xreg. Is there a way to fit model with interactions between ARx and some variables from xreg?

Comment: You could always add a new column to your xreg that is composed of the (lagged data)*(xreg) and then run the model again.

Comment: Yes, i know that, I just wanted a model suitable for the predict function which makes this way really ineffective...

Comment: I don't quite get what you say!

Comment: when you specify a model and save it to a variable, you can use it as an input for predict function, which returns prediction for specified steps ahaed. In such a model you cannot use this workaround, because you dont know what your lagged data from prediction will be.

Comment: Take a look at this: [Arima  Forecast Equations](https://onlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat510/node/66/)